# How to test event and style unsafecss in lit-html using jest and jsdom

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, lit-element, lit, lit-html

I'm trying to create a unit test for my lit-html element using jest.
I want to check if the click event is working as expected.

To test an event that changes from active to disable when clicked.

```js
// my-lit-html-toggle.ts
const TAG = 'my-lit-html-toggle';

@customElement(TAG)
export class My-lit-htmToggle extends LitElement {
  @property({ type: Boolean })
  public active = false;

  @property({ type: Boolean })
  public disabled = false;

  public static styles = unsafeCSS(toggleSwitchStyles);

  public render(): TemplateResult {
    const classes = {
      active: this.active,
      disabled: this.disabled,
    };
    return html`
      <div class="toggle ${classMap(classes)}" @click=${this.toggleActive}>
        <div class="toggle-switch"></div>
        <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  private toggleActive() {
    const onToggle = new CustomEvent<ToggleSwitchEvent>('onToggle', {
      detail: {
        active: (this.active = !this.active),
      },
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(onToggle);
  }
}
```

```js
// Test JEST
import { html, render } from 'lit'; 

describe('Given my-lit-html-toggle', () => {

    it('Should switch from active to disabled', async function () {
      const switchHandler = jest.fn();

      render(html`<my-lit-html-toggle active .click="${switchHandler}" ></my-lit-html-toggle>`, document.body);
      await Promise.resolve();
      document.body.querySelector(TAGNAME)?.click()
      await waitFor(() => expect(switchHandler).toBeCalledTimes(1));
    });
})
```

The click event was called but the class did not changed.
Jest error:

```js
    expect(element).toHaveClass("disbled")

    Expected the element to have class:
      disbled
    Received:
      toggle-switch active

      38 |       );
      39 |       const cut = document.body.querySelector(TAGNAME)?.shadowRoot;
    > 40 |       expect(cut?.childNodes.item(2)).toHaveClass('disbled');
         |                                       ^
      41 |     });
      42 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation. The describe method within jest is wrong.
**This code will never trigger a event within the  my-lit-html-toggle.ts** because jest do not know what ***.click*** is. The active and inactive state is set after an event and not as attribute.

Incorrect way

```
 it('Should switch from active to disabled', async function () {
  const switchHandler = jest.fn();

  render(html`<my-lit-html-toggle active .click="${switchHandler}">
              </my-lit-html-toggle>`, document.body);
  await Promise.resolve();

  document.body.querySelector(TAGNAME)?.click()
  await waitFor(() => expect(switchHandler).toBeCalledTimes(1));
});
```

Correct solution use ***@click=${(e: CustomEvent) => onclick(e.detail)}***

```
it('Should switch from active to disabled', async function () {
 const onclick = jest.fn()

   render(html`<my-lit-html-toggle @click=${(e: CustomEvent) => onclick(e.detail)}>
              </my-lit-html-toggle>`, document.body);
   await Promise.resolve();

  document.body.querySelector(TAGNAME)?.click()
  await waitFor(() => expect(onclick).toBeCalledTimes(1));
});
```